# Extra headers not being sent via url.el

Tags: rest, emacs, curl, lisp, elisp

Following is my elisp code (credentials obviously being fake):

```
(defvar assembla-username  "foo")                                                                                                                                                                             
(defvar assembla-password  "bar")                                                                                                                                                                           
(defvar tickets-url "http://www.assembla.com/spaces/aWx7Oas2352cwqjQWU/tickets/")                                                                                                                       

(defvar assembla-auth-header (concat "Basic " (base64-encode-string (concat assembla-username ":" assembla-password))))                                                                                              

; curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -u "foo:bar" http://www.assembla.com/spaces/aWx7Oas2352cwqjQWU/tickets/                                                                                      
(defun get-tickets()                                                                                                                                                                                            
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  (let ((url-request-extra-headers                                                                                                                                                                                   
         '(("Accept" . "application/xml")                                                                                                                                                                            
           ("Authorization" . assembla-auth-header)))))                                                                                                                                                                                
  (url-retrieve tickets-url (lambda (status)                                                                                                                                                                
                                       (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer)))))
```

Based on monitoring outgoing request headers, the "Accept" header is not being set. I'm pretty sure this is what's redirecting me to the login page, as the curl request commented out works perfectly and does set the Accept header.

That being said, is there something specifically I'm doing wrong, and/or are there better wrappers for doing a lot of REST calls in elisp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not evaluating your `assembla-auth-header` variable and you call `url-retrieve` outside your `let`, at which point `url-request-headers` has reverted to its original state. It also seems that you might need to use `url-mime-accept-string` instead of adding it to the extra headers.

```
(defun get-tickets()
  (interactive)
  (let ((url-mime-accept-string "application/xml")
        (url-request-extra-headers
         `(("Authorization" . ,assembla-auth-header))))
    (url-retrieve tickets-url (lambda (status)
                                (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
```

I would suggest trying something like this and seeing if this at least passes along the *Accept* and *Authorization* headers correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately I get two headers sent with Accept, such as: Accept: */*
User-Agent: URL/Emacs (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; TTY)
Accept: application/xml

Comment: @user652650 I did a quick `M-x apropos` and found `url-mime-accept-string` maybe that can work? I have no idea, but it looks like the extra headers aren't overwriting the original ones.